# conversion from double to float in c++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, floating

I am new to programming. Here is part of my assignment, which requires using pass-by-reference. After I compile it and type in the values for win, draw and loss respectively,it returns me nothing. I don't know whether it is due to the problem in calling the function or the floating point.

```
void Cfunction(int win, int draw, int loss, float& point)

{
point = win * 2.5f + draw * 1 + loss * 0;
}

int main(void)
    {
        int win, draw, loss;
        float point;
        cout << "Please input the game record in the following order: win draw loss " << endl;
        cin >> win >> draw >> loss;

        Cfunction(win, draw, loss, point);
        cout << "The total score for the team is " << point << endl;

    }
```

Comment: Please attempt some debugging

Comment: You aren't using doubles anywhere. Have you tried debugging the code? What are the input values? BTW, a *function* that doesn't return a value isn't a good idea.

Comment: Your code works for me. What numbers are you inputting?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I assume "assignment that requires pass by reference" is a requirement on the function written, in other words, teacher doing "do it this way because I say so".

Comment: "it returns me nothing" - what does it mean ?

Comment: You should also check for successful input, a la `if (cin >> win >> draw >> loss) { Cfunction... / cout... } else cerr << "invalid input - next time, enter three numbers\n";`.

Comment: never use `cin >>` - it only ends in confusion. You'd be better off asking for the 3 values separately, reading a whole line from cin with getline, and then getting the (single) number from the string. If you can't do that, then at least print out the values you get so you can check they are what you think they are..

Comment: This code works as expected - http://ideone.com/sXyc6G

Answer (score 1):

Look good to me.

You could verify that your `cin >> ...` has finished by adding a `cout << "calculatin total score...." << std::endl;`.

(Note: `std::cin >> wins` has the `wins` variable passed by reference, too :))

Indeed, as @David Hefferman suggested, learn to use the debugger.  Will save you a huge amount of time in the (very near) future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me too. You do know that you have to add the numbers one by one on their own lines, e.g. 5 , 3 , 4 ?